# Is it possible to delay Fade's transition?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Goal: I want Fade's transition to happen after a certain time has passed (ex: 4000 milliseconds).

Here is a fragment of my code:

```
<Fade in timeout={{ enter: 8000 }}>
  <Box display="flex" justifyContent="center">
    <IconButton href="https://soundcloud.com/jyillamusic">
      <Soundcloud />
    </IconButton>
    <IconButton href="https://www.instagram.com/justinyum98/">
      <Instagram />
    </IconButton>
  </Box>
</Fade>
```

Expected result: With `enter: 8000`, I expect the transition to happen after 8000 milliseconds.

Actual result: The transition starts at 0 milliseconds, finishes after 8000 milliseconds.

Does Fade support delaying the Fade transition by some specified time?

(Looking at [Fade's API](https://material-ui.com/api/fade/), I assumed that `duration.enteringScreen` meant that it was the amount of milliseconds before the transition occurs, but I'm probably mistaken.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fade does not implement a delay feature, however you can **manually handle your transition status** using `in`.

> ## in
>
> Show the component; triggers the enter or exit states
>    **type**: boolean
>   **default**: false

In code you could do :

```
<Fade in={this.state.in} timeout={{ enter: 8000 }}>
  <Box display="flex" justifyContent="center">
    <IconButton href="https://soundcloud.com/jyillamusic">
      <Soundcloud />
    </IconButton>
    <IconButton href="https://www.instagram.com/justinyum98/">
      <Instagram />
    </IconButton>
  </Box>
</Fade>
```

And on display run a timeout to wait and create the delay

```
this.state = {
    in: false
};

setTimeout(() => {
    setState({ in: true });
}, 8000);
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. If you were looking for a non state alternative. @equintas answer below was what i was looking for.

Comment: You should clear the timeout, so you do not get state updates on unmounted components.     useEffect(() => {
        const timer = setTimeout(() => {
            setFadeIn(true);
        }, 800);
        return () => {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        };
    }, []);

Answer (score 9):

In "[Components > Transitions > Zoom demo](https://material-ui.com/es/components/transitions/#zoom)" of Material UI doc there are some examples in order to achieve it; a bit more elegant than touch the state!

In esence, you can pass a `style` attribute to `Fade` component and set the delay (`transitionDelay`). In the code below we iterate a result array and causes each individual element be showed with a 100ms delay from previous.

```
 {profileItems.map((pi, index) => (
    <Fade in={profileItems.length > 0}
          timeout={{ enter: 500, exit: 250 }}
          style={{ transitionDelay: `${index * 100}ms` }}
          key={`asi-${pi.key}-${index}`}>
       <span>
         <DisplayItem profileItem={pi} />
       </span>
   </Fade>))}
```

Comment: I used the sx property, but apparently you have to use the style property. I will use a timeout solution instead

Answer (score 0):

To piggyback off of [sebastienbarbier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4762763/sebastienbarbier), you could create a custom transition component that will handle the state for you by simply passing a `delay` prop.

Here is what the component would look like (I added additional useful props):

```jsx
const MyFade = ({
   children,
   in: In = true,
   timeout = 1000,
   delay = 0
}) => {
   const [isIn, setIsIn] = useState(In && delay === 0)

   useEffect(() => {
      if (delay > 0) {
         setTimeout(() => setIsIn(true), delay)
      }
   })

   return (
      <Fade in={isIn} timeout={timeout}>
         {children}
      </Fade>
   )
}
```

And then for your specific issue to have it wait 4000ms:

```
<MyFade in timeout={{ enter: 8000 }} delay={4000}>
  <Box display="flex" justifyContent="center">
    <IconButton href="https://soundcloud.com/jyillamusic">
      <Soundcloud />
    </IconButton>
    <IconButton href="https://www.instagram.com/justinyum98/">
      <Instagram />
    </IconButton>
  </Box>
</MyFade>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seem to work for me without Fade:

```
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
```

> 

```
<List>
                  {[
                    'Inbox',
                    'Starred',
                    'Send email',
                    'Drafts',
                    'foo',
                    'bar',
                    'baz',
                  ].map((text, index) => (
    <ListItem
     key={text}                 
     sx={{
     transitionProperty: 'all',
                                transitionDuration: '750ms',
                                ...(open && {
                                  opacity: 1,
                                  transform: 'translateY(0)',
                                  transitionDelay: `${index * 150}ms`,
                                }),
                                ...(!open && {
                                  opacity: 0,
                                  transform: 'translateY(100%)',
                                }),
                              }}
                            >
```

or

```
<ListItem
 key={text}
 style={{ transitionDelay: open ? `${index * 150}ms` : '0ms' }}                     
>
```